# How do you forward a file into s3 from a post request

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, http-post, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy a website that can handle post requests. To do so I have set up an api gateway that invokes a lambda function. The lambda is structured as below:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    var ht = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><title>Document</title> </head> <body><form method = "post"> <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename"> <input type="submit"> </form></body></html>'

    
     if (JSON.stringify(event['requestContext']['http']['method']) == '"GET"'){
    const    response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": ht,
    "headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    }
    
    
}
return response;
 
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(event['requestContext']['http']['method']) == '"POST"'){
        // forwards the uploaded file into s3
        
        return 1
    }
    
    
};
```

Right now upon the get request, the html page rendered contains a button to choose a file and one to submit it. The idea is that upon pressing submit a file is uploaded hence triggering the post request. What I was wondering how exactly can I extract this file from the requests within the 'Post' if statement(where the second comment is) so that I can then send it to an s3 bucket? I was also wondering how instead of having the html being one line, how can I place it into its own index.html file and call it within the lambda function?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://github.com/mmakadiya/aws_lambda-API_gateway-Import-XML-data/tree/main with the code.

event['body'] will have the content of your imported body.

--

import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# TODO implement
print("V.1")
print("========================")
print(event)
print("========================")

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3.Bucket("my-files-maulik").put_object(Key = "MyFirstFile.xml", Body = event['body'])

print("**********body = " + event['body'])
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```